# Chrome Extensions: Get Current Console to Send Up to Server

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-extension, remote-debugging

Is it possible to get the current output of the console in any form?

For example, it would be great for my debugging purposes if whenever a test failed on a user's machine, I could call something like:

```
console.trace()
output = console.dump()
$.post("https://<myserver>/debug/logs", { "console" : output } );
```

which would wrap up the current console output and send it up to a server.

In a more general sense, I would like to include a button to submit a bug report, and would like each bug report to be packaged with as much contextual data as possible.

Full Disclosure: I'm aware I could just avoid calling `console.log()` and instead call my own specialized logging function for storing/uploading error logs.  I include the `console.trace()` line to motivate why this intermediate-step solution wouldn't be ideal, but ultimately the reason I don't want to do it is because I am building a general debugging module that can be used immediately in any extension (so the average developer using `console.log` or `console.error` will be able to insert one or two lines to set up remote debugging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible in Chrome. You can use the handy `console.dir()` command to see what functions are available for console. I didn't see anything that would get any text from console.

You get the list like this:

```
console.dir(console)
```

Comment: Yes, I was going through those functions before asking the question.  Unfortunate that this functionality isn't exposed.  I'm going to inspect the Chromium source code, but I might just need to hack a wrapper around console and attach my wrapper to the window.

Comment: OK, so after inspecting the source code, there is no way to do this now.  http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.devtools.console.html should eventually make it possible (assuming they ever upgrade it out of experimental).

Comment: thanks for the research, i would also like to have that functionality - did you come up with any workaround?

Comment: btw, maybe this helps you (it didn't help me in my special case): http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

Comment: @Stefan looks like it is now possible for extensions with http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger.html.